# What does method name /number on Elixir methods mean?

Tags: elixir

I have been learning Elixir and have come accross the methods that you can use when using tuples. This applies to all methods but what does the /number mean next to a method name? For example

```
iex(1)> put_elem/3
```

This is a method used on tuples but what does the /3 denote?

Comment: its called `arity`. The number of arguments a function can take and its also used when we want to pass arguments to the anonymous function             `&(function_name/arity)` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an Arity of the function. The Arity is not Elixir nor only CS specific.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity):

> In logic, mathematics, and computer science, the arity of a function or operation is the number of arguments or operands that the function takes.

As soon as Elixir allows you to create functions with the same name, but with different arguments it needs to distinguish them. That is why you can see the Arity specified in some cases. Mostly to understand which version of a function to use.

You can find more about functions and arity [here](http://whatdidilearn.info/2017/10/06/functions-in-elixir.html#arity).

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated and have discovered that the /number, denotes the amount of arguments that function requires.

```
foo/2
```

foo requires 2 arguments.

Comment: It's also often called "arity"

Comment: Thank you for that, that is exactly what its called. Never seen it called that but had a quick look and yeah thats what its called